# segmentation fault in C programming

Tags: c

I started learning C programming and in this program I am trying to get user input and then a line at a time and decide if it contains non-int characters. I've been trying this method:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
if (isalpha(n))
{
 i = -1;
}
```

I googled a bit and learned the function `isalpha` is good way to do it. However, I'm getting a segmentation fault every time I test the fragment above with non-int characters (letters for example). Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: How is n declared? Have you checked the return value of scanf? It tells you how many input items were assigned.

Comment: What are n and i declared as? Can you give some context?

Comment: What is a "non-int character"?

Comment: I declare n and i simply as:    int n;int i;

Comment: a non-int character is anything that not an integer. This can be a puncuation or members of the alphabet.

Comment: 125 is an integer. Interpreted as a character, that's }.

Comment: @Chris: you seem to be confusing integers (these are things like -10, 50, 10^99 and the like) and (strings of) digits like "90", "000110". isalpha will tell you if a character - like 'a' - is an a-z. It doesn't do anything sensible for general integers, but %d reads integers - not characters (ie. 9 rather than '9'). (not to say if you wanna check for digits, you'd better use isdigit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier forces `scanf()` to only accept strings of digits. Given anything else, it will fail and leave `n` unfilled (and assuming you didn't initialize `n` before, it will be filled with garbage).

The crux of the problem is that `isalpha()` expects a value between 0 and 255, and has an assertion to enforce it. At least on my VC++ compiler, it causes a crash with an access violation when given an invalid value (in non-debug mode).

To solve this you just have to switch to a `%c` format specifier. Converting `n` to a `char` would also be advisable as that makes your intent of reading a single character clearer.

**EDIT:** Given your clarifications in the comments, you can leave everything as is and simply check the return value of `scanf()` instead of going the `isalpha()` route. It returns the number of values read successfully, so when it encounters a non-integer or end of file, it will return 0. E.g.:

```
int main() {
  int n;
  while (scanf("%d", &n)) {
    printf("Got int: %d\n", n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you're getting a seg-fault. I'd have to see more of your program.

But using "%d" for scanf will only accept integer values and you'll get "0" for n that isn't an integer and therefore isalpha(n) will always be false and i will never be set to -1.

Perhaps you aren't initializing i and therefore it is never set. If you are referencing it later, that's probably the source of your seg-fault.

Use scanf("%c", &n), like this:

```
int main(char** argc, int argv) {
  char n = 0;
  int i = 0;
  scanf("%c", &n); 
  if (isalpha(n)) { 
    i = -1;
  }
  printf("you typed %c, i=%d", n, i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a character buffer to store the value in. Scan it as a string, and then use `isalpha()`:

```
char buffer[32];
sscanf("%32s", buffer);

// loop and check characters...
if(isalpha(buffer[i])) ....
```

Note the use of `%32s`, this is to prevent buffer overflows (32 == size of buffer)

Comment: The reason why I initiated n as an int is because the goal of the program is to read line by line, get all the int and add to a total. When I find the end of file, I have to output the total. But one of the requirements is that I have to read until EOF or a non-int character is found.

Comment: You **must** use N-1 in the format string when you use N in the variable declaration!

Answer (score 1):

Given that `n` is an integer, we can diagnose that you are reading a value into `n` which is not in the range 0..255 plus EOF (normally -1), so that the code for `isalpha(n)` is doing something like:

```
(_magic_array[n]&WEIRD_BITMASK)
```

and the value of `n` is causing it to access memory out of control, hence the segmentation fault.

Since `scanf()`:

1. Returns the number of successful conversions, and
2. Stops when there is a non-integer character (not a digit or white space or sign) in the input stream,

you can use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char n = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &n) == 1)
        printf("you typed %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```